# Взять left и top элементов массива js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как взять `left` и `top` всех элементов table[] с помощью jQuery?
И отправить post запрос с данными каждого из массивов table[].

```css
.room {
width:100px;
height: 100px;
background: gray;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="room" id="table[1]" style="left: 10px; top: 10px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[2]" style="left: 20px; top: 20px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[3]" style="left: 30px; top: 30px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[4]" style="left: 40px; top: 40px;"></div>
```

Comment: надо использовать только id?

Comment: Да, нужно сопоставить переменную в js с id элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** Используйте метод [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) для того, чтобы взять часть строки. К примеру, вызов `str.slice(6, -1)` извлечёт символы с седьмого по второй с конца строки.

```
'table[1]'.slice(6, -1) // => вернёт '1'
'table[4]'.slice(6, -1) // => вернёт '4'
```

```js
const tables = [];

$('.room').each(function(index, node) {
  tables.push({
    id: ($(node).attr('id')).slice(6, -1),
    left: $(node).css('left'),
    top: $(node).css('top')
  });
});

console.log({
  tables
});

/**
 * Пример AJAX запроса.
 *
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'send.php',
  data: {
    tables // $_POST['tables']
  },
  // Чтобы jQuery распарсил ответ как JSON.
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('success');
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert('error');
    console.log({
      [error.status]: error
    });
  }
});
*/
```

```css
.room {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="room" id="table[1]" style="left: 10px; top: 10px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[2]" style="left: 20px; top: 20px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[3]" style="left: 30px; top: 30px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[4]" style="left: 40px; top: 40px;"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2** Используйте пользовательские [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) атрибуты для ассоциирования и хранения данных, связанных с элементами DOM.

```
<div class="room" data-table="3" style="left: 30px; top: 30px;"></div>
```

**3** Если вам не нужно передавать единицы измерения `px` для `left` и `top`, используйте метод [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
const tables = [];

$('.room').each(function(index, node) {
  tables.push({
    id: $(node).data('table'),
    left: $(node).css('left'),
    // Метод parseInt, если вам не нужно
    // передавать единицы измерения `px`.
    top: parseInt($(node).css('top'), 10)
  });
});

console.log({
  tables
});
```

```css
.room {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="room" data-table="1" style="left: 10px; top: 10px;"></div>
<div class="room" data-table="2" style="left: 20px; top: 20px;"></div>
<div class="room" data-table="3" style="left: 30px; top: 30px;"></div>
<div class="room" data-table="4" style="left: 40px; top: 40px;"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = [];

[...document.querySelectorAll('.room')].forEach(room => {
  const styles = getComputedStyle(room);
  const id = room.id;
  let object = {};

  object = {
    'left': styles.left,
    'top': styles.top,
    'id': id
  }

  array.push(object);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.room {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="room" id="table[1]" style="left: 10px; top: 10px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[2]" style="left: 20px; top: 20px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[3]" style="left: 30px; top: 30px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[4]" style="left: 40px; top: 40px;"></div>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как узнать какая позиция какого элемента? Как обозначить имя?

Comment: что Вы имеете ввиду под словом "позиция"?

Comment: `left` и `top` элемента

Comment: ничего не понял, поподробнее объясните, пожалуйста)

Comment: Как указать в массиве что `left: 10px` и `top: 10px` относятся к элементу с `id="table[1]"`

Comment: обновил11111111

Comment: А можете сделать что бы id было так `"id": "1"`

Comment: Сделаете?) Очень нужно

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Можете id обрезать регуляркой `"table[33]".replace(/table\[(.*)\]/,"$1")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const post = () => {
  let arr = document.querySelectorAll('.room');

  let newArr = [];

  arr.forEach(i => {
    let obj = {};
    obj.name = i.id;
    obj.left = getComputedStyle(i).left;
    obj.top = getComputedStyle(i).top;

    newArr.push(obj);
  });

  let json = JSON.stringify(newArr);

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('POST', 'server.js', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xhr.send(json);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

    //...
  }

}

post();
```

```css
.room {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="room" id="table[1]" style="left: 10px; top: 10px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[2]" style="left: 20px; top: 20px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[3]" style="left: 30px; top: 30px;"></div>
<div class="room" id="table[4]" style="left: 40px; top: 40px;"></div>
```

С помощью vanilla